# Assign a number to each post in a custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm building a page that is displaying a list of posts (potentially they will be randomly displayed) in a grid.

These posts are a custom post type, and each post is assigned to a single taxonomy for organization.

For each post I'd like to display an associated number. I don't mean the post ID, as that isn't specific enough. Basically, I'd like to treat the custom post type as its own list of posts. So the first post in that post type will be post #1, the second would be #2, and so on.

As well, if it's possible to do this by taxonomy, that would be even better. But I'd settle for just numbering the posts in the custom post type in general.

My solution so far is this: create a function in functions.php that loops through the custom post type, and assigns a number (starting at 1 for the first post) to each post as a custom field. This function runs whenever the page that displays the posts is loaded. So that function runs first in its own loop, and then the page does a normal loop and gets each number.

This solution works cosmetically. I'm getting the result that I want. However, it's not very efficient as it will run any time the page is loaded.

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps a way to automatically assign a number to a post whenever a post is published? I understand that if a post is deleted, there'd be a skipped number. That's acceptable.

I hope this is clear.

I edited this for clarity, as well as updating the current solution which has changed. I also removed the block of code I have here because it's no longer necessary.

Comment: Please add your code you have coded so far

Comment: I've added the code now :)

Comment: What do you mean by "post number" ?

Comment: I basically want the index number of the post. So the first post I write would be 1, the second one would be 2, third is 3, etc. So when viewing the list of posts, it would say "Use # 1, "Use # 2" etc.

Comment: do you mean by post id, or menu order?

Comment: Ideally it would be a fixed number assigned to each post, I guess post ID would be the closest to that. But not the real ID, because that ID takes into account everything else in the site. I want the IDs to be starting from 1 in this custom post type.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

**EDITED CODE**

Add the function in your functions.php file

```
function Get_Post_Number($postID){
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$postNumberQuery = new WP_Query('orderby=date&posts_per_page=-1');
$counter = 1;
$postCount = 0;
if($postNumberQuery->have_posts()) :
    while ($postNumberQuery->have_posts()) : $postNumberQuery->the_post();
        if ($postID == get_the_ID()){
            $postCount = $counter;
        } else {
            $counter++;
        }
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_query();
$wp_query = $temp_query;
return $postCount;
}
```

This is your loop

```
   <ul id="uselist">
    <?php
    query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'use',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'posts_per_page' => 6
    ) );

    if ( have_posts() ) : 
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

    $currentID = get_the_ID();
    $currentNumber = Get_Post_Number($currentID);

            $usecategory = get_term_by('id', get_field('use_category'), 'usecategory');
        ?>
            <li>
                <div class="use" style="border-bottom:15px solid <?php the_field('category_colour', $usecategory); ?>;">
                    <div class="useimage" style="background-image:url(<?php the_field('image'); ?>);">
                        <?php if (get_field('display_vimeo_video') == 'yes') { ?>
                            <div class="playicon"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/playicon.png" /></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="useinfo">
                        <div class="usecatimage">
                            <img src="<?php the_field('category_image', $usecategory); ?>" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="usecatandtitle">
                            <h2 class="usecat"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $usecategory->name; ?> / Use <?php echo $currentNumber ; ?></a></h2>
                            <h3 class="usetitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="usename">
                            <?php the_field('name'); ?>, <?php the_time('M d'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php

        endwhile;
    else :
    endif;
    ?>
</ul>
```

I have not tried this code, but it should work.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. This isn't what I'm looking for unfortunately. I want the post number to be coming from the post itself. So the fifth post that I write should have the number 5 attached to it somehow. So even if I have the posts displaying in random order, it'll always show that specific post as post number 5.

Comment: do you mean post id?

Comment: Edited the code, please try and let me know, is this you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks! I understand what it's trying to do, but it's messing up the main loop. For some reason it's just outputting 2 posts (there are 6 currently) and both with the same ID and name, etc. I'm trying to tweak the code, but perhaps you know what's wrong with it?

Comment: More specifically, it's outputting a post ID of 0, and outputting the current page's title. (this code is in a page template).

Answer (score 0):

I added 2 lines below, one setting the post count, and one printing the number sequentially  look for: $postNumber

```
<ul id="uselist">
        <?php
        query_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'use',
        'order' => 'desc',
        'posts_per_page' => 6
        ) );

        if ( have_posts() ) : 

             $postNumber = 1; //add a sequential post number!

            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                $usecategory = get_term_by('id', get_field('use_category'), 'usecategory');
            ?>
                <li>



                    <div class="use" style="border-bottom:15px solid <?php the_field('category_colour', $usecategory); ?>;">
                        <div class="useimage" style="background-image:url(<?php the_field('image'); ?>);">
                            <?php if (get_field('display_vimeo_video') == 'yes') { ?>
                                <div class="playicon"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/playicon.png" /></div>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="useinfo">
                            <div class="usecatimage">
                                <img src="<?php the_field('category_image', $usecategory); ?>" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="usecatandtitle">
                                <h2 class="usecat"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $usecategory->name; ?> / # <?php echo $postNumber++; ?> //POST NUMBER WILL INCREASE SEQUENTIALLY HERE</a></h2>
                                <h3 class="usetitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="usename">
                                <?php the_field('name'); ?>, <?php the_time('M d'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php
            endwhile;
        else :
        endif;
        ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply :) Unfortunately this isn't what I mean. I want to assign (or retrieve) a number that is assigned to each individual post. So the first post I write in this custom post type would be number 1. The second is number 2, etc. And I want to retrieve that number for display. The reason for this is that these posts won't always be displayed in order.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could pull this off easily using [Custom Fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields). For each post in your custom post type, add a custom meta field, say `post_number` and manually enter the value for that field. 
And, display the value in your page using [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

```
<ul id="uselist">
    <?php
    query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'use',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'posts_per_page' => 6
    ) );

    if ( have_posts() ) : 
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
            $usecategory = get_term_by('id', get_field('use_category'), 'usecategory');
        ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_number', true); ?>
                <div class="use" style="border-bottom:15px solid <?php the_field('category_colour', $usecategory); ?>;">
                    <div class="useimage" style="background-image:url(<?php the_field('image'); ?>);">
                        <?php if (get_field('display_vimeo_video') == 'yes') { ?>
                            <div class="playicon"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/playicon.png" /></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="useinfo">
                        <div class="usecatimage">
                            <img src="<?php the_field('category_image', $usecategory); ?>" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="usecatandtitle">
                            <h2 class="usecat"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $usecategory->name; ?> / Use #</a></h2>
                            <h3 class="usetitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="usename">
                            <?php the_field('name'); ?>, <?php the_time('M d'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php
        endwhile;
    else :
    endif;
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi there. I thought of that, but this is a client site and they wouldn't want to do that :) If the custom field would automatically populate, then I'd use it.